# How to add Tag and subitem in listview c#

Tags: c#, listview, subitem

I want to display tag and subitem  in my listview , those items come by using while statement. here the code

```
int id = 0;
                    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        id++;
                        string[] columns = line.Split(',');
                        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
                        item.Tag = id;
                        item.SubItems.Add(columns[1]);
                        lv_Transactions.Items.Add(item);
                    }
```

subitems cab be displayed but the tag just appear blanks. Someone know to fix this please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Tag property is not displayable. You will need to add the contents of the tag as a subitem or otherwise embed it in the data you are showing to the user.

You have three choices on how to implement this:

1) `ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(id.ToString());`

2) `item.Text = id.ToString();` (this is effectively the same as 1)

3) `item.SubItems(id.ToString());` if you want the id to appear in the list of subitems.

**Update**

SubItems will only work correctly if you have defined Columns in the ListView and have set the ListView's `View` to `View.Details`.

Assuming that you have not done this, the following line:

```
item.SubItems.Add(columns[1]);
```

should be modified to be:

```
item.Text = columns[1];
```

Comment: i still dont understand, can you gave me example?

Comment: @BijakAntusiasSufi: Updated the answer with 3 options.

Comment: No i know how to add subitem, i want to display Tag as checkbox but it is not appear you can see it here http://tinypic.com?ref=i2tt37

Comment: @BijakAntusiasSufi: I couldn't see anything at that link. Do you have anything in the listview or just checkboxes at the moment?

Comment: @BijakAntusiasSufi: Updated the answer with what I think will solve your problem.

Comment: @BijakAntusiasSufi: Ok, that's what I thought you were after. You need to add `item.Text = id.ToString();` to your code.

Answer (score 1):

To make the item have text, which I assume you want to show the 'id', you will want this:

```
item.Text = id.ToString();
```

The tag field is ignored by the control, and exists as a way of 'tagging' the source data to a control, so it can be retrieved later on (for example, when processing an event that was trigged by the control).